# how to increase the output values without increasing datasets?

Tags: dataset, matlab, roc

I am using MatLab 2017a. I have dataset of 12 video. I have to plot ROC curve of this dataset. For this purpose, I have used perfcurve command.

```
[X,Y,Threshold,AUC] = perfcurve(labels,scores,true);
```

I have scores, and labels for perfcurve. The issue is this that when I execute this command, I get 13x1 array of X, Y , threshold values. How can I increase these values to approximately 50x1 without increasing dataset. Is there any other way to increase these values without increasing the dataset?

Answer (score 0):

No. Why would there be?

You have 12 videos, so that's what gets plotted.

Whether you are doing an ROC, running a regression, calculating AUC or even just computing means and medians, the data you have is the data you have.

Adding more points to the ROC *is* adding more data.

Comment: This is being automatically flagged as low quality, probably because it is so short. Can you expand on this, Peter? It might help if you explain a little about how a ROC works, & why that means there would only be 12, given 12 data.